# How to add exponential function in this java applet program?

Tags: java, applet

i've made this program but i dont know how to add exponential function in it. I've tried it but failed. Kindly help me with java coding will really appreciate your answers thanks.

And here's the code:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;



public class factorialFunction extends Applet implements ActionListener
{

    Label lbl1,lbl2;
    TextField txt1,txt2;
    Button btn1,btn2;

    public void init()
    {

        lbl1=new Label("Enter a value: ");
        lbl2=new Label("Result:");
        txt1=new TextField(10);
        txt2=new TextField(10);

        btn1=new Button("Factorial");
        btn2=new Button("Exponential");

        add(lbl1);
        add(txt1);
        add(btn1);
        add(btn2);
        add(lbl2);
        add(txt2);

        btn1.addActionListener(this);
        btn2.addActionListener(this);
    }   

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {

        int n=Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
        int fact=1;

        if(ae.getSource()==btn1)
        {
            if(n==0||n==1)
            { 
                fact=1;
                txt2.setText(String.valueOf(fact));
          }
          else
          {
              for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
                  fact=fact*i;
          }

          txt2.setText(String.valueOf(fact));
       }
       else if(ae.getSource()==btn2)
       {

       }


    }

}
```

I dont know how to proceed further please help me i need to submit my lab project thank you!

Comment: Factorial and exponential are completely different functions. Also, don't tag spam (you're using Java, so there is no reason for you to tag this c and c++)

Comment: a good note : applet and AWT are old, you should use swing or javafx

Comment: If you need a function that will compute factorial, we can help. But I'm not sure why you included the code you have above.

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: i was showing you my code. Please provide me with the factorial function code Mr. Matthew Cliatt?

Comment: Assuming that your exponential function involves only positive integer (1,2,3,...) exponents, the code will look very similar to your code for factorial. Only difference: you won't multiply `fact` by `i`, the loop counter, you'll multiply by the base (the number being raised to the whole number power).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for can be found in the Java Math libraries.  Take a look at [Math.pow(a,b)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow%28double,%20double%29)